# How to limit query to end of pagination in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, rest, pagination

I'm dealing with a paginated REST api on a US government website, and I'm running into errors at the end of the query, specifically dealing with pagination.

As it stands, there's no way to tell when the query will end due to the nature of the pagination, and that it's updated every day with additional pages.

The attempt I've tried is

```
for x in x_list:
    for y in y_list:
        for z in range(0, 1000):
            
           response = requests.get(url)
           
           if response.status_code != 200:
               break # this doesn't seem to work as it breaks the loop

           a_json = pd.normalize(response, record_path = ['results'])
    
    do_stuff_to_converted_dataframe
```

However, this returns an error that the object is not serializable.

This wouldn't be an issue, if my code were working the way my mind thinks it does, and breaks the loop to continue to the next nested loop in `for y in y_list`.

Is there a way to change it to something along the lines of:

```
for x in x_list:
    for y in y_list:

        pagination_limit = function_that_checks_maximum_pages

        for z in range(0, pagination_limit):
            
           response = requests.get(url)
           
           if response.status_code != 200:
               break 

           a_json = pd.normalize(response, record_path = ['results'])
    
    do_stuff_to_converted_dataframe
```

Comment: Check the response headers, maybe they use Content-Range, you just don't know about it. And ofc. check the documentation first, they should write about pagination.

Comment: The documentation says nothing about page limits, unfortunately. Headers also doesn't return anything regarding the page or failed query.

Comment: I would ask support if they have one.